# Return all positions of a certain element in a list without recursion, but with list generators

Tags: haskell, recursion

we are asked to write a function ourselves in Haskell that, when given a list and a certain element returns a new list, containing the ordered positions of that element in that list.

I already tried that for a long time now, but the one I currently have still uses recursion, which the task says we are not supposed to use.

```
allPositionsOf :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [Int]
allPositionsOf e es = [i | i <- [0 .. (length es - 1)], IsAtPos e es i]
    where
         isAtPos :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int -> Bool
         isAtPos e (x:xs) 0 
                          |x == e    = True
                          |otherwise = False
         isAtPos e (x:xs) i   = findAtPosition xs e (i - 1)
```

I know there is the !! and other functions similar, but is it possible to just use list generators and keep it simpler ?

Comment: What do you mean by list generator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like that right?

```
allPositionsOf :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
allPositionsOf b xs = [ i | (i,x) <- zip [0..] xs, x == b]

λ> allPositionsOf 'b' "dfbhjbd"
[2,5]
```

you almost got it already - the only I just added one further *trick*:

I `zip` the list up with `[0,1,2,...]` to get indizes and elements side by side, pull out a `(index,element)` pair (here `(i,x)`), filter out everything where `x == b` and then finally return the indizes from the pairs

Comment: That is amazing <3 . But don't you have to write `b (x:xs)` instead of `b xs`?

Comment: no - if I'd do this it would not work for empty lists (as this pattern would not match those) and I don't need to deconstruct the list here anyways (the list-comprehension does this for you)

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot